# Making a .fla in Flash Professional then importing into Flash Builder

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flash-cs5

I'm making a simple .fla in flash professional cs5 that has a List component. I then want to export this .fla from flash professional into flash builder where I have my real program code.

Then I would like to be able to dynamically add text elements to the list, as well as having an event listener.

I know that the instance name of the List in cs5 can be used in the actionscript3 code but I'm not sure how I am suppose to export/import it to be able to do this.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

You have several choices:

1. Create a swf, and compile that entire swf into the Flex project
2. Create a swf and compile just the symbol(s) you are using into the Flex project
3. Create a swf and dynamically load it into a swfloader
4. Create a swc

For the embedding solutions, check [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html)

For dynamic loading, see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f9c.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7efa) and [here](http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2009/01/example-of-casting-contets-of-swfloader.html)

If you want to make a swc, look [here](http://www.brickabracka.com/jd/2008/09/exporting-swc-files-for-use-in-flex.html)